# Неопределенная ссылка на виртуальную таблицу класса

Tags: c++, классы, виртуальная-функция

```
struct B {
    int i{1};
    virtual void f();
};
struct D : B {
    int j{2};  
};
```

Вышеуказанная ошибка выдается после такого простого использования:

```
int main()
{    
    D d;
    cout  << d.i;
    return 0;
}
```

Не обьвив функцию как виртуальную, естественно, не было бы никакой ошибки.
Вопрос:   причем тут виртуальная таблица, если я обращаюсь только к полю базовой структуры?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то у меня выскочила только одна ошибка - отсутствие определения `B::f()`. Наверное, ваш компилятор хотел сказать это же, просто другими словами: ведь раз есть виртуальная функция, от должен создать vtable, но что туда положить, если адрес `B::f()` неизвестен (определения-то нет)?

Comment: однако быстро вы разобрались... но кому то не понравился ни вопрос, ни ответ, но испугался высказаться

Comment: @ARHovsepyan кстати, Вы забыли виртуальный деструктор. :)

Comment: @Croessmah,  спасибо, вы правы, но  написал только  с целью задать вопрос...